# How do I subscribe to events for child elements of a view

Tags: ember.js

My view contains an element.  What is the best way to respond to mouseEnter and mouseLeave events for only that element?

Does ember want me to convert that element into a view?

Does ember want me to call `this.$().on('mouseEnter', '.my-child-element', someHandler)` and `.off` it myself in `didInsertElement` and `willDestroyElement` respectively?

Or am I missing a more appropriate approach?

Comment: What about creating a subView around this element ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this, but I always come to the conclusion that you create a view for anything that needs to respond to events. You could also use an action handler for very simple events in a template.

`{{action "my_action" on="mousedown"}}`

I would still recommend using a view though as you will most likely need to know more info about what happened and want access to the view and models bound to that element.